# Handling imageButtons

Tags: java, android

I am writing a simple application in android and I have this problem:

First of all, I use imageButtons in order to load images from .xml files located in my `res/layout` directory.  The point is: can I handle them as normal buttons in Java?  I mean are there somewhere instantiated?

Because when later I use `onClickListeners` I want them to trigger an event when clicked(load another `.xml` file in another `.java` file).

And thing else :
Somewhere in my `MAinActivity.java` I have these lines of code :

```
Button imageButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
imageButton2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

What is exactly the use of `findviewById`?

Do I have to do to `R.Java` and find the class id and add this field?  Or can I understand it automatically?

Comment: I am always impressed by people "Writting" anything without even trying to undrstand basics of what they try to do. RTFM mate, RTFM!

Comment: I would prefer a real answer and not general instructions

Comment: No. You'd prefer someone to do your job. This most likely is not gonna happen. Maybe you should not be doing programming with that attitude?

Comment: Keep your advise for yourself. I am new to android developing and i try to understand what is going on. You are not helping at all.

Comment: app_dev if you're new to Android development, then I'd suggest you take the advice of people on here and learn how to read the documentation, it'll save you plenty of time down the line. As for advice, if you're not looking for it, then I'd suggest deleting your account, as advice is all you're going to find here (aside from the odd troll, but they're far and few between). The number of upvotes that @marcin has on his comments should prove to you that he's not alone in sharing that opinion. I'm with him

Comment: Am I the odd troll...?

Comment: Did you see some advice before? There are people that really want to help even if the questions can be answered very easily. I am looking for helpful advice and not for people that are pretending to be smarter. That's the difference.

Answer (score 1):

**findViewById()** is finding the "id" of so-and-so object (in this case an image button) and correlates that XML to the Java code you're currently looking at.  You need an XML file (not an R.java).  Android apps usually have **XML files** for **presentation and structure** of the app whereas the **Java** is supposed to be **the logic and database**.

When I first started programmed phone apps, it was confusing for me too.  However, as a programmer, you want to always research your topics.

Look at some simple examples online:

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-example/

Also, this is a slow and steady (and very detailed!) guide.  It will help understand the overall design and structure of Android phone apps.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Finally, to know where exactly "**R**" is referring to, you must see **setContentView()**:

```
//you should have this method in your program
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //here is where it decides the exact XML file this Java class refers to.
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    addListenerOnButton();

}
```

onCreate() is usually where you want to set the context (context meaning which XML file you are referring to).  Then every other method in that Java class will know to look in that XML file.

Comment: I have many .xml files in my layout directory. In each file i use the same names for the buttons. I just want to know if it understands the right imageButton i am refering to the .xml file i am using above and if i can really handle my imageButton as a button (in order to be clicked etc)  Thanks.

Comment: I made an edit that will hopefully answer your question.  Remember to look at both my links.  The first one is a very straightforward and simple example, so look at that first.

Comment: Ok. No problem. Even if i had read the documentation probably there was a misunderstanding. Anyway, thanks.